# Does Nick ever turn on you?

Tags: fallout-4

After the quest Dangerous Minds, you speak to Nick and either he impersonates Kellogg or something of Kellogg remains after exploring his memories using Nick as a host.

What surprised me though, was the dialogue options after this outburst were all the wrong way around, the options for Nick to continue with you were on the top and left rather than bottom and right, with the options on the bottom and right being "You're a risk" and "Go Alone".

Does Nick ever turn on you if you keep him as a companion after completing Dangerous Minds?

Comment: Related: I just killed a settler in Sanctuary, and the entire settlement turned on me, including most of my companions. Nick even stole one of my nearby Power Armors just to kill me.

Comment: Well I would expect that, that will happen in most settlements!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Per his [wiki entry](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Nick_Valentine):

> Nick speaks a sentence after going into Kellogg's brain, in Kellogg's voice. However, it doesn't affect the storyline in any way past this quest.